# How to make this (generics) type specification work?

Tags: java, generics

The following code works fine with generic type parameter `Column` but how do I make this work with type parameter `Column<N>` where `N` is type used for field `columns`.

```
    class Cols_Iterables2<Column> extends Iterable2<Column>{ 
        ColumnList<N> columns;

        public Cols_Iterables2(ColumnList<N> columnList) {
            this.columns = columnList;
        }

        @Override
        public Column get(int index) {
            return columns.getColumnByIndex(index);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `Column`? Is it a generic type?

Comment: Try this: class Cols_Iterables2<N, Column<N>> extends Iterable2<Column<N>>{

Comment: @MikeArgyriou: Dont know wny netbeans shows error `> expected` when I try your line

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: It is `interface Column<C>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your `ColumnList<N>` has the `getColumnByIndex` method defined roughly as follows

```
class ColumnList<N> {
   public Column<N> getColumnByIndex(int index) {
```

just parametrise your `Cols_Iterables2` class with `N`:

```
class Cols_Iterables2<N> extends Iterable2<Column<N>> { 
    ColumnList<N> columns;

    public Cols_Iterables2(ColumnList<N> columnList) {
        this.columns = columnList;
    }

    @Override
    public Column<N> get(int index) {
        return columns.getColumnByIndex(index);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes this works!! Could you explain this line `class Cols_Iterables2<N> extends Iterable2<Column<N>>` in your answer ? Why you added `N` as type parameter in `Cols_Iterables2` but `Column<N>` with `Iterable2` ?

Comment: Any generic parameter such as `N` needs to be defined somewhere: you need to give the user of your class or method a way to specify the type. For independent methods, each using some parameter `N`, you could add `<N>` to the method declarations. In your case however, you use expect `N` to be the same across multiple declarations in your class so you need to parametrise the class itself or else how will the compiler know which class to use for `N`. As it is now, you will need to provide the actual class when you construct instances, e.g. `new Cols2_Iterable2<Integer>(colList);`